# How can I use .htaccess to stop redirecting from subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a domain, "domain.com", and subdomain, "sample.domain.com", and all files related to both are stored in `domain.com/folder`. How can I use .htaccess to prevent requests from "sample.domain.com" from going to `domain.com/folder/index.php?title=sample`?

This is what I'm currently using in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{http_host} .
 RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.domain.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{http_host} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com /folder/index.php?title=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

But there is one thing - a redirect is external (the browser goes to a new link), and I need to redirect this was on the server side, so that the user thought he was actually working with the subdomain. Can can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com /folder/index.php?title=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /folder/index.php?title=%1 [L,QSA]
```

The `R` flag tells the rewrite engine to redirect, and having the `http://www.domain.com` in the rule's target is also an implicit redirect.

Comment: In a "folder" folder I have htaccess: RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?title=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?title=$1
And I replace my htaccess in root folder as you said. And delete htaccess in "folder" folder. But it still redirects to domain.com/folder/sample/

Comment: @user2135517 are you sure your browser isn't caching the 301 (which means permanent) redirect?

Comment: I checked it in all my browsers. Its works same to all of it.